# What's the proper way to eliminate the "margin" on a <li> within a <ul>?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a list of li elements inside a ul with associated style classes (below). What I want is for every list item to be along the left edge of the page. Putting borders around both ul and li I can see that the li items are indented exactly 40px inexplicably.

I've tried margin-left: 0px on both elements and I've tried list-style:none; which does help to eliminate the bullets and slide everything left **up to the indestructible 40px margin**.

I've determined through trial and error that if I do this in my li:

```
left: -40px;
position: relative;
```

I get the desired result but the margin merely pops to the right side / tail of each li which is less troublesome visually but still a terrible hack. There must be a way to make it disappear?

My style code looks like this:

```
ul.selectorlist
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: none;
    margin: 0px;

    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}


li.channel
{
//  left: -40px; // <- Does the trick but COME ON, REALLY?!

    width: 100%;
    background-colour: black;
    font-family:georgia;
    font-size:18px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;

    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}
```

Note:

I have also played around with:

```
list-style-position: inside / outside;
```

Which actually pops the li bullets on the left and right sides of the 40px line.

Comment: Don't forget `text-indent` as well...

Comment: Are you sure that your margins are taking precedence and aren't being overwritten by a selector with higher specificity?

Comment: Tools like Firebug or the Chrome developer tools can be a big help in tracking things like this down. Also, if you're not using any kind of HTML reset styles, it might be possible you're running into some weird browser default.

Comment: This is a very simple test and the only other margin: 0 is inside body and it is also set to 0.

Comment: Marc B, I tried text-indent and it had no effect in either selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little experimenting (in FireFox 11) shows that the default layout for a list includes a 40px left padding, which is there to make room for the bullets.

Add

```
padding:0;
```

to the styles for the `<ul>` and your mysterious gap should disappear. However, this may have undesirable consequences with regard to the bullet position. Getting rid of the bullets or setting `list-style-position` to `inside` are both possible remedies, depending on your particular layout requirements.

Note that this padding is on the `<ul>` element, which, when you add borders, is visually similar to a margin on the `<li>`. This is one reason why development tools like Firebug or those included in Chrome and IE are so useful—it's very easy to see the box model of any element.

Comment: That's it! I actually had "padding: none" which is, of course, a bug. As soon as I changed it to 0 - the problem disappeared and I am now getting exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing around with list-style-position
ie:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

or

```
list-style-position: outside;
```

Comment: This actually pops the bullet to the left or right side of the invisible 40px margin. So adding, 'outside', for example, drops the bullet into the 40px space between the real 0 and the 40px invisible margin.

Comment: This is worth trying. However, setting `list-style-position` to `inside` produces usually undesirable results when the line wraps (the second line of text is left-aligned to the bullet rather than to the text). I assume that's why `outside` is the default.

Comment: Greg B - Though it's not reflected in the question snippet (I'll edit), yes, I tried that and it doesn't fix the problem. Interestingly, the lack of it causes my ul to move about 5px vertically on the page. When I put it back in, the whole list tightens it up to the top edge again - which is bizarre.